# Why does order matter in function definition?

Tags: pattern-matching, agda

Given these definitions for lists:

```
data List (A : Set) : Set where
    []   : List A
    _::_ : (x : A)(xs : List A) → List A

length : {A : Set} → List A → ℕ
length []        = zero
length (_ :: xs) = suc (length xs)

lookup : {A : Set}(xs : List A)(n : ℕ) → (isTrue (n < length xs)) → A
lookup [] n ()
lookup (x :: xs) zero p = x
lookup (x :: xs) (suc n) p = lookup xs n p
```

and booleans:

```
data Bool : Set where
    true  : Bool
    false : Bool

data False : Set where
record True : Set where

isTrue : Bool → Set
isTrue true     = True
isTrue false    = False
```

This compiles with no errors when `_<_` is defined as:

```
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ; suc; zero)

_<_ : ℕ → ℕ → Bool
_     < zero   = false
zero  < suc n  = true
suc m < suc n = m < n
```

but if I switch the order of the top two definitions to:

```
_<_ : ℕ → ℕ → Bool
zero  < suc n  = true
_     < zero   = false
suc m < suc n = m < n
```

I then get the error:

```
isTrue (n < length []) should be empty, but that's not obvious to me
when checking that the clause lookup [] n () has type
{A : Set} (xs : List A) (n : ℕ) → isTrue (n < length xs) → A
```

This suggests to me that `n < length []` is matching against `zero  < suc n  = true`, which it shouldn't because `length []` equals `zero`, or `suc m < suc n = m < n`, which it shouldn't do because that is the last definition for `_<_` (and also the same reasoning from the other case).

Am I misunderstanding how agda matches with function definitions, or how the absurd pattern works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, Agda translates definitions by pattern matching to a case tree (see the documentation at [ReadTheDocs](http://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.4.1/language/function-definitions.html#case-trees)). To construct this case tree, Agda always first looks at the first clause. Hence depending on the order of the clauses, the resulting case tree may be different. In your example, the case tree for the first definition of `_<_` is (in pseudo-syntax):

```
m < n = case n of
          zero   -> false
          suc n' -> case m of
            zero   -> true
            suc m' -> m' < n'
```

while the case tree for the second definition of `_<_` is

```
m < n = case m of
          zero   -> case n of
            zero   -> false
            suc n' -> true
          suc m' -> case n of
            zero   -> false
            suc m' -> m' < n'
```

In effect, in the second definition Agda has split the single clause `_ < zero = false` into two clauses `zero < zero = false` and `suc m < zero = false`, preventing `n < zero` to reduce any further.

To stop Agda from splitting clauses like this, you can put `{-# OPTIONS --exact-split #-}` at the top of your file (or add `--exact-split` to your command-line flags to Agda).

If you want to learn more about how definitions by pattern matching are elaborated to a case tree, you can read [our upcoming ICFP paper](https://jesper.sikanda.be/files/elaborating-dependent-copattern-matching.pdf) about the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Jesper's correct reply also points to another way of making `lookup` work with the second definition of `_<_`: just match on `n` yourself so that it is unambiguous which branch of `_<_` to take:

```
lookup : {A : Set}(xs : List A)(n : ℕ) → (isTrue (n < length xs)) → A
lookup [] zero ()
lookup [] (suc _) ()
lookup (x :: xs) zero p = x
lookup (x :: xs) (suc n) p = lookup xs n p
```